# QtDBUS: Send Enums over DBUS

Tags: c++, qt, enums, ipc, qtdbus

I'm using qt dbus binding in c++.

Currently I'm able to send any custom types (e.g.: class, structs) over dbus but I am not able to send an enumeration.

[I also tried this link here, but I do not get it](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/D-Bus/CustomTypes#Adventurous_serialization_of_enumerations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem:

First create a new header file called `enums.h` which looks like:

```
#ifndef ENUMS_H
#define ENUMS_H

#include <QtDBus>
#include "enumDBus.h"

enum Color {
    RED = 0,
    BLUE,
    GREEN
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Color)

#endif  /* ENUMS_H */
```

Note following line `#include "enumDBus.h"`, you can find this header file [here](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/D-Bus/CustomTypes#enumDBus.hpp).

So after you declared the enum you can declare a method which takes the enum as argument, in this example I declared following method in `calculator.h`:

```
void setColor(Color color);
```

The implementation for this method:

```
void Calculator::setColor(Color c)
{
    switch (c) {
    case BLUE: std::cout << "Color: blue" << std::endl;
        break;
    case GREEN: std::cout << "Color: green" << std::endl;
        break;
    case RED: std::cout << "Color: reed" << std::endl;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Color: FAIL!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Now let's generate the Interface description (XML), use following command

```
qdbuscpp2xml -M -s calculator.h -o com.meJ.system.CalculatorInterface.xml
```

The generation of method which contains custom types doesn't work properly, so we need to do some adjustments:

```
<!DOCTYPE node PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Object Introspection 1.0//EN" "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/introspect.dtd">
<node>
  <interface name="com.meJ.system.CalculatorInterface">
    <method name="setColor">
        <annotation name="org.qtproject.QtDBus.QtTypeName.In0" value="Color"/>
        <arg type="(i)" direction="in" name="c"/>
    </method>
  </interface>
</node>
```

With this XML file we can simply create our adaptors and interfaces classes.

In our `main.cpp` (on client and server!) we have to register our custom type:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    qRegisterMetaType<Color>("Color");
    qDBusRegisterMetaType<Color>();
}
```

#### Client Side

Include generated `calculatorInterface.h` and `enums.h` in your `main.cpp`.

Now you can simply call your method:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    qRegisterMetaType<Color>("Color");
    qDBusRegisterMetaType<Color>();

    QDBusConnection dbus = QDBusConnection::sessionBus();

    com::meJ::system::CalculatorInterface *calculator = new com::meJ::system::CalculatorInterface("com.meJ.system", "/Calc", dbus);
    if (calculator->isValid() == false) {
        cerr << "ERROR: " << qPrintable(calculator->lastError().message()) << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    Color c = GREEN;
    calculator->setColor(c);
    std::cout << qPrintable(calculator->lastError().message()) << std::endl;

    exit(0);
}
```

If everything worked you should see following output at your server program:

```
~# Color: green
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution which uses macro and does not have boost dependency. 
You need to write below statement in your header file to declare << and >> operators.

For example:

```
DECLARE_ENUM_DATATYPE(QProcess::ProcessState)
```

and in one .cpp file add below statement to define << and >> operators.

```
CREATE_ENUM_DATATYPE(QProcess::ProcessState)
```

Both above functions require below file, you can save it as enumDBus.hpp

```
#ifndef _ENUM_DBUS_HPP
#define _ENUM_DBUS_HPP

#include <QtDBus/QDBusArgument>

#define DECLARE_ENUM_DATATYPE(ENUM_TYPE_DBUS)\
     QDBusArgument &operator<<(QDBusArgument &argument, ENUM_TYPE_DBUS value);\
     const QDBusArgument &operator>>(const QDBusArgument &argument, ENUM_TYPE_DBUS &val);


#define CREATE_ENUM_DATATYPE(ENUM_TYPE_DBUS)\
     QDBusArgument &operator<<(QDBusArgument &argument, ENUM_TYPE_DBUS value)\
     {\
         argument.beginStructure();\
         qlonglong newVal = (qlonglong)value;\
         argument << newVal;\
         argument.endStructure();\
         return argument;\
     }\
     const QDBusArgument &operator>>(const QDBusArgument &argument, ENUM_TYPE_DBUS &val)\
     {\
         argument.beginStructure();\
         qlonglong result = 0;\
         argument >> result;\
         val = (ENUM_TYPE_DBUS)result;\
         argument.endStructure();\
         return argument;\
     }

#endif //_ENUM_DBUS_HPP
```